# Selmer $p$-Groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

I searched so many articles about Bloch-Kato $p$-selmer Groups defined by $p$-adic representation but it seems that $p$ is not necessary to be odd.
Hence, I am wondering if it is worth considering Bloch-Kato 2-selmer Groups (2-primary) or Bloch-Kato conjecture for $p=2$ (2 part of Bloch-Kato Conjecture). Besides, there are some papers avoid considering $p=2$ and prove the theorem under the condition $p$ is odd prime.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What, exactly, is your question? Given a compatible family of p-adic Galois representations (e.g. arising from an elliptic curve), the p-adic Bloch--Kato Selmer group is well-defined for all $p$ including $p = 2$. Often $p=2$ is more difficult than other primes, so it is sometimes -- but not always -- omitted. Are you asking for examples of papers proving things about 2-adic BK Selmer groups?

Comment: Very appreciate it! Exactly,  Bloch--Kato Selmer group can be well-defined for any prime via $p$-adic representation and Tate twist. Since some papers related  $p$-adic Bloch--Kato Selmer group avoid considering $p=2$, I am curious about whether the case $p=2$ does not worth considering.

Comment: For example, I read this paper-- Flach, Matthias. "A finiteness theorem for the symmetric square of an elliptic curve.." Inventiones mathematicae 109.2 (1992): 307-328. <http://eudml.org/doc/144023>. about finiteness of Blach-Kato Selmer groups associated an elliptic curve. However, in this paper there is the assumption  $p\geq 5$, so I am wondering if the case of $p=2$ is still true or just trivial case or hard case  for even prime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be asking what the reason is for many papers on $p$-adic Selmer groups to assume throughout that $p > 2$: is because the case $p = 2$ is less interesting, or because it is more difficult?

The answer is definitely the latter. For many theorems concerning p-adic Selmer groups, there is an argument that works to prove the theorem for all sufficiently large primes, but $p = 2$ (and sometimes $p = 3$ as well) present extra difficulties. So it is common to deal with the "generic" cases of large $p$ first, and subsequent papers can then fill in the small primes later. See for instance [this paper](http://www.math.caltech.edu/%7Eflach/mainconjecture-at-two3.pdf) by Flach, which is devoted to filling in the $p = 2$ case of a theorem proved by Burns and Greither for $p \ge 3$.